# Using SquishIt with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, squishit

I'm trying to use SquishIt with MVC3.  I downloaded the Nuget package and I can see it under the Project Reference. But I can't call any of the methods in it. I also tried importing the SquishIt framework, but that doesn't work either.  Any pointers please?

Thanks

Comment: Deleted and repeated the nuget installation of squishit a few times.  And it finally works!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found out that you have to recompile after adding SquishIt from NuGet. Then it works like a charm.